# C program with big arrays compilation under Windows

Tags: arrays, c, memory, out-of-memory, mingw-w64

In my project in C, I have a **third-party** library where big arrays (>13 000 000 elements) are used.

```
real_t T[NVCMIN*NVCMIN];        /**< Reverse triangular matrix, A = [0 T]*Q'. */
real_t Q[NVMAX*NVMAX];          /**< Orthonormal quadratic matrix, A = [0 T]*Q'. */
```

Under Linux, everything works fine  with `-mcmodel=large`.

But under windows, I get **bss section** errors like this.

Error:

```
/cygdrive/project/embeddedLapack/qpOASES/Source/OQPinterface.c:218:(.text+0x879): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_REL32 against `.bss'
/cygdrive/project/embeddedLapack/qpOASES/Source/OQPinterface.c:219:(.text+0x8a9): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_REL32 against `.bss'
/cygdrive/project/embeddedLapack/qpOASES/Source/OQPinterface.c:260:(.text+0xd18): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_REL32 against `.bss'
out/objs/mpc_controller_test_ef.o: in function `mpc_controller_ef':
/cygdrive/project/tests/mpc_controller_test_ef.c:163:(.text+0x35d): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_REL32 against `.bss'
/cygdrive/project/tests/mpc_controller_test_ef.c:276:(.text+0xb01): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_REL32 against `.bss'
/cygdrive/project/tests/mpc_controller_test_ef.c:276:(.text+0xbab): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_REL32 against `.bss'
/cygdrive/project/tests/mpc_controller_test_ef.c:528:(.text+0x13c7): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
```

Options

> ```
>    -mcmodel=medium
>        Generate code for the medium model: the program is linked in
>        the lower 2 GB of the address space.  Small symbols are also
>        placed there.  Symbols with sizes larger than
>        -mlarge-data-threshold are put into large data or BSS
>        sections and can be located above 2GB.  Programs can be
>        statically or dynamically linked.
>
>    -mcmodel=large
>        Generate code for the large model.  This model makes no
>        assumptions about addresses and sizes of sections.
> ```

I tried this compiler options under windows:

```
-Wl,--stack,8589934592 -mcmodel=large
```

and

```
-Wl,--stack,8589934592 -mcmodel=medium -mlarge-data-threshold=60000
```

By decreasing arrays I am able to compile. But I am limmited to 2GB.    It looks like the compiler is not using `-mcmodel=large`

```
text   data bss        dec        hex      filename  
833917 8784 2141833472 2142676173 7fb6a4cd .\out\mpc_c.exe
```

Comment: It's running out of `.bss` memory, not of stack memory.

Comment: Without knowing the details, it seems as if executables on Windows are linked with a limited size for `.bss`. Can't you use `malloc()` to allocate as much memory as needed?

Comment: @thebusybee  It looks like mcmodel=large is not working properly.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, stack is used for other variables .  It looks like mcmodel=large is not working properly.

Comment: why don't use dynamic allocation?

Comment: @phuclv this arrays are part of **third-party** library

Comment: Did you try other compilers on Windows?

Comment: @BohdanPakhaliuk Who said that you can't change a 3rd party's library? There are no information regarding the license. Depending on your app and the library's licenses it may be possible to edit the library's code